# Notation for a string of objects

Tags: notation, boolean-algebra

Is there a commonly used notation for a string of objects? The particular situation I am interested in is a string of elements from a Boolean algebra. The elements in the string may be expressions using the Boolean operations $\wedge$ and $\vee$. When this situation occurs I enclose such an element in parentheses. A typical example of such a string is
$$(a_{1} \wedge b_{1}) \ldots (a_{m} \wedge b_{1}) (a_{1} \wedge b_{2}) \ldots (a_{m} \wedge b_{2}) \ldots (a_{1} \wedge b_{n}) \ldots (a_{m} \wedge b_{n})$$
What I would like is something like a summation sign so that I could save space and improve clarity. So that this string could be written in a manner similar to
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{m}\sum_{j = 1}^{n} (a_{i} \wedge b_{j}) \text{,}$$
but without the implied operation of addition.

Comment: $\{ (a_i \land b_j) \}_{i,j}$

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA If you turn your comment into an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proposal is to use:

> $\{ (a_i \land b_j)_{1 \le i \le n, 1 \le j \le m} \}$.

Comment: A string is not a set, and order matters.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** A commonly used notation for creating strings is *[concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language#Operations_on_languages)* of letters taken from an alphabet $V$.

We could then write
\begin{align*}
&(a_{1} \wedge b_{1}) \ldots (a_{m} \wedge b_{1}) (a_{1} \wedge b_{2}) \ldots (a_{m} \wedge b_{2}) \ldots (a_{1} \wedge b_{n}) \ldots (a_{m} \wedge b_{n})\\
&\qquad=\prod_{l=1}^n\prod_{k=1}^m(a_{k} \wedge b_{l}) 
\end{align*}
where non-commutativity of concatenation has to be appropriately addressed.

Comment: I use $a_{1} \ldots a_{n}$ for simply described strings. There  is an equivalence relation on  the set of strings. Permutations of the elements in a string  does not alter the equivalence class.